# Jersey client retrieve list of Object with generic type

Tags: java, jersey, moxy

I am working on the client end of an API that can perform searches on a variety of objects. All search functions return a list of objects like the below:

```
{
   score : ...
   object : {}
}
```

Score is how relative the result is and object is the object itself. What I'd like to be able to do is implement a `Result<T>` POJO that can handle the results for a variety of different objects using Jersey/MOXy but I am unsure as to how to do this (or if it's even possible). Thoughts?

I tried creating the `Result` object with a `T item` attribute, annotating it with `@XmlAnyElement` and unmarshalling using `response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Result<Object>>>(){});` but it always returned null.

Comment: I've never done this, so not sure if it would work, but maybe a Result superclass with a bunch of children?

Comment: That would probably work - you mean one child per each different object type? Maybe I'll do that - was just hoping for something a bit lighter. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. Idk, not as nice as what you were doing though.

Comment: Do all of your "object" classes have the right annotations, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, they do. I'm successfully de-serializing in other calls.

Comment: Actually, @xdhmoore, you were pointing me in the right direction. See answer and thanks again!

Comment: Glad my vague ramblings helped! :)

Answer (score 2):

Erm... turns out my approach was right after all. My objects weren't annotated with @XmlRootElement because it was not needed in other calls. This was leaving the objects as `ElementNSImpl`. So the answer to my question is basically in the question. Also had to add `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` to T attribute.